# Reactive UI from client side arrays/collections

Tags: meteor

I'm just starting to learn meteor, and I'm wondering what is the proper way of implementing an MDI(multiple document interface) UI like the one provided by jQuery Window plugin (http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/) in meteor.

My initial thought was to have an array of Window object that is stored in the Session, then have the template loop through the list of windows, and render them accordingly.

However, this would mean that whenever the user opens or closes a window, I will have to call Session.set() with the modified array, which results to a full re-render of the entire UI, potentially making the user loose his current work state (unless unique ids are generated on the fly for the form elements to be used).

In addition, the UI would support drag & drop and resizing, which should result to updates to the Window object, but updating the Window object will not trigger reactive rendering unless I call Session.set again with the windows array, which will then result to another re-render of the entire UI.

What would be the proper approach for this? such that re-rendering could be limited only to the window that was created/closed/adjusted?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Store the info to a `Collection` and render it from that? Or use `Template.preserve`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I read in another post that client side only collections do not support inserts? In such case I would have to create a collection of the server side, and for each session I will have to create the record for it without an effective way of cleaning up. I will check out Template.preserve and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Just checked Template.preserve. Please correct me if I'm wrong with the idea.. So the approach will be for me to specify all windows as the selector for preserve (e.g. div.windows) , and then use map it to a function that compares it against a session variable, right? 

How about the use of collection? can I use a client side only collection for this case? and how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a "scratchpad" collection named `Windows`:

```
Windows = new Meteor.Collection(null)
```

You can then store window size, position, etc. In this collection, but it won't be synced to the server.

Alternatively, you could store the window arrangement as part of the user object in Mongo, which means the window arrangement would persist between sessions (and all browser tabs would share the same window arrangement).

Comment: Thanks Gaelan,

But the main issue is how to prevent the whole Window's collection from being re-rendered whenever a single window is opened/closed/resized. 

any ideas?

Comment: @hint As of Meteor 0.8, only necessary parts of your interface are rerendered. If nothing changes, meteor does not render unnecessary.